# Reading string from command line argument in MPI c

Tags: c, command, mpi, command-line-arguments

I have to write an MPI c program. My compiler does not recognize datatype string though I have added string.h . I want to read a string from the command line and pass it to the function given below

```
int find_rows(char * file)
{
    int  length=0;
    char buf[BUFSIZ];
    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen(file, "r");
    while ( !feof(fp))
    {
         // null buffer, read a line
        buf[0] = 0;
        fgets(buf, BUFSIZ, fp);
        // if it's a blank line, ignore
        if(strlen(buf) > 1) 
        {
            ++length;
        }

    }
    fclose(fp); 
#ifdef DEBUG
    printf("lFileLen = %d\n", length);
#endif
return    length;     

}
```

This function works when I have

```
 char file[50] = "m5-B.ij";
```

and then call

```
nvtxs = find_rows(&file );
```

But gives me segmentation fault when I give

```
 nvtxs = find_rows(argv[1] );
```

Can someone please help ?

Comment: Are you passing an argument to `main()`? Check return value of `fopen()`.

Comment: Yeah. I can read and print the value of argv[1] using fprintf or sscanf. I just cannot pass it to the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
find_rows(&file );
```

call

```
find_rows(file );
```

`file` is already a pointer. You were passing the address of the pointer to the function.

Then later in the function `find_rows` you try to open invalid file and operate with `fp` which is a null pointer causing  *undefined behaviour*.

*EDIT*

Your call `nvtxs = find_rows(argv[1] );` is correct. The problem is `fp=fopen(file, "r");` might not be able to open the file, if the file does not exist or it cannot find the file.

Comment: The program works when I pass 

   find_rows(&file );
But I dont want to hardcode the file name. I want to get it from the command line using argv. I am unable to do this

Comment: @Lopez Check if `fopen(file, "r");` returns NULL.

Comment: Thank you Armin and Eddy . But the point is I want to eliminate the file part and use the argv [1] instead

Comment: @Armin : Yes. It doesnot open the file. Fp returns NULL

Comment: @Lopez  the file does not exist or it cannot find the file.

Comment: Thank you Armin. I gave the right parameter when I hardcoded it but gave wrong file name while executing.